# Magento2: Category id not showing at backend

Tags: magento2, category

I've installed Magento version 2.1.1 on my localhost. Then created few categories at backend. The issue is when I click on the category, it doesn't show ID of that category after the name of that category as it is showing in Magento1 (http://prntscr.com/e2z79c).

Is this a issue in Magento2? How can I show the ID of category?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 is not showing `categories Ids` as it is showing in M1. You can check `category id` in the URL after selecting any category. If you want to show category id then you need to override core functionality of category page.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this, this seems to be a bug and it seems to be fixed (see https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/14028aad37ee7435d89eb3b647e6d03ecd8e2e13) but I still have it in Magento 2.1.5.

A quick fix is :
find or extend .. vendor\magento\module-catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit.php and (somewhere around line 102 in public function execute) simply add this line and comment out the other line:

```
// new line:
$resultPageTitle = $categoryId ? $category->getName() . ' (ID: ' . $categoryId . ')' : __('Categories');
$resultPage->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog::catalog_categories');
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Categories'));
// remove: $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($categoryId ? $category->getName() : __('Categories'));
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($resultPageTitle);
$resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Catalog Categories'), __('Manage Categories'));
```

Now it will show your category name like this: MyCategory (ID: 15) in the top left corner.